# Connect to mongodb with simba odbc driver with kerberos authentication

Tags: mongodb, odbc, kerberos, keytab, simba

I am using the simba odbc driver with sql connector on windows 7 machine. I am trying to connect to a remote server that has the data using Kerberos authentication using a keytab file. I am having a difficult time figuring out how to do this. I saw this information on the following Link: [Simba Odbc Install guide kerberos](http://www.simba.com/products/MongoDB/doc/v2/ODBC_InstallGuide/win/content/odbc/m2/windows/authenticating/kerberos.htm) , but it could not understand how to use the keytab file or give path to it in the Simba administrator tool. Can anyone please point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use MIT Kerberos. In this case, you need to initialize your user-principal by doing `kinit -kt file.keytab user@REALM.COM`.

The driver will use the default principal.